# How to use local storage for input(checkbox) values selected by user. Need to be in plain javascript (no Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of categories selectable via checkboxes in HTML. My goal is to have the user select the categories that they would like using the checkboxes, and have their selection saved for when they return.

I have seen Jquery solutions that look simple, but for this I do not want to use Jquery. I can get the checkbox selections to persist for the one session, but cannot get the selections to stay for when I open the next session.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chbox" value="animals"checked>
<label for="animals">Animals</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" class="chbox" value="city">
<label for="textures">City</label><br>



function checksValue() {
var checkedBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chbox');
var result = [];
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (checkedBoxes[i].checked === true) {
        result += checkedBoxes[i].value + ", "; 
    }
}
localStorage.setItem("checkedBoxes", JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Do you have any code where you've attempted to set the checkbox values after getting the `checkedBoxes` item from local storage, or is that where you've got stuck?

Comment: `result` starts as an array and then becomes a string. You should `push` to it, not append like it was a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

Assuming that these checkboxes are in a `<form>` tag:

#### Phase I

> - Get [reference to the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms): `var main = document.forms[0];`
> - Next [collect all of its form controls into a NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) and [convert it into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from): `Array.from(main.elements)`
> - Then run the array through [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [check which ones are checked and which ones aren't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator): `return chk.checked ? 1 : 0;`
> - `map()` returns an array of ones (checked) and zeros (not checked): `var values = [0,1,0,0,1,1]`
> - [Store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) that [array as a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) into `localStorage` under a key (ex. `chx`): `localStorage.setItem('chx', JSON.stringify(values));`

---

#### Phase II

> - Create an [IIFE](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6): `!(function() {{...})()`
> - [Get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) the saved string from `localStorage` under its key and [convert it back into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse): `var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chx')) || [];`
> - Run [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) through the array and on every `1` found in the array, [check the checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) that corresponds to the current index: `m.elements[idx].setAttribute('checked', true);`

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Mo3VZlBsUd4bZxXneJ2q/)

### Demo

**Note: the following demo will not allow `lobalStorage` to work, to review a functional demo go to this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Mo3VZlBsUd4bZxXneJ2q/).**

```js
var main = document.forms[0];

!(function(m) {
  var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chx')) || [];
  values.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    if (val === 1) {
      m.elements[idx].setAttribute('checked', true);
    }
  });
})(main);

main.addEventListener('change', saveChx);

function saveChx(e) {
  var chxArray = Array.from(main.elements);
  var values = chxArray.map(function(chk) {
    return chk.checked ? 1 : 0;
  });
  console.log(values);
  return localStorage.setItem('chx', JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

```html
<form id='main' onsubmit='return false'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you for the help. It was really cool learning your solution.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: could you please explain in your Plunker above why you used !(function(m)? I am confused why the function has ! before it and why the function itself is in brackets

Comment: IKR? It's crazy looking but it's very effective if you want to run a function only once and immediately upon being read. Read this [section](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6#5892)

Answer (score 0):

Here I see three steps:

1. when the page loads, load saved checkboxes from local storage;
2. one took everything from the storage, check what needs to be checked;
3. create an event listener for each checkbox that saves che check status;

First things first, lets define the data structure we will save and retrieve, I think this could be a good one:

```
{
  "animals": true | false,
  "city": true | false,
  ...
}
```

Now, define an helper method to retrieve the status of the checkboxes:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'my_checkboxes' // you can use your key here

const loadStatus = () =>
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || {}
```

Here nothing special: parse the item retrieved from the local storage or return an empty object if no status has been saved before.

Being able to load, we need to be able to save:

```
const saveStatus = checkboxes => () => {
  const status = checkboxes.reduce(
    (map, checkbox) => Object.assign({}, map, { [checkbox.value]: checkbox.checked }),
    {}
  )

  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(status))
}
```

This method takes an array of checkboxes and returns an event handler (for the checkbox change event). It basically map values to their check status.

Linking everything together in a `window.onload` event handler should solve your problem:

```
window.onload = () => {

  //  retrieve checks from the local storage
  const checks = loadStatus()

  // for each key value pair...
  Object.entries(checks).forEach(
    ([value, isChecked]) => {
      // ...sets the check status
      document.querySelector(`[value="${ value }"]`).checked = isChecked
    }
  )

  // add event listener that update the local storage when a checkbox change its status
  const checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.chbox'))
  checkboxes.forEach(
    checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('change', saveStatus(checkboxes))
  )

}
```

I know some parts might seems hard, I'm glad to help in case.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you need.

Keep in mind, I use ES6, so if you need to use an older version of JS you should translate the code in an older version.

```js
// Select all the document elements with class .chbox
let cboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.chbox');

// Responsible to handle the user click on the selected checkboxes.
let handleCheckBoxEvent = function (e) {
  // If the checkbox is checked
  if (e.target.checked) {
    // Then save the value in the local storage.
    localStorage.setItem( e.target.value, e.target.checked );
  } else {
    // Else, if the checkbox is unchecked, remove the value from the local storage
    localStorage.removeItem( e.target.value );
  }
};

// If more than 0 checkboxes found
if ( 0 < cboxes.length ) {
    // Iterate over the found elements
    cboxes.forEach(
      cb => {
        // If the current iterated checkbox name exists in the local storage
        if ( localStorage.getItem( cb.value ) ) {
          // Add the checked property so the checkbox appears as checked.
          cb.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }

        // Add an event listener to the current iterated checkbox and bind it with the handleCheckBoxEvent function.
        cb.addEventListener(
          'change',
          handleCheckBoxEvent
        );
      }
    );
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chbox" value="animals">
<label for="animals">Animals</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" class="chbox" value="city">
<label for="textures">City</label><br>
```

Also, keep in mind, my solution is pretty basic, as it introduces a new key for each selected checkbox in the localStorage. For each case, there are many implementations which both could be right.

Comment: The one downvoted, can explain the reason? This snippet works as it should, so I don't see why I got downvoted.